# Limit Range Text Length

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm running into an issue where I've set up Data Validation for characters that = 10 in a specific column in Excel. My issue is, if a user pastes over the cell, the data validation gets overwritten. Is there a way to accomplish a text limit by using VBA, that'll alert the user to only have 10 characters in a cell within a defined range? One that won't get overwritten if a user pastes over a cell?

Comment: Note that if a value overrides data validation, the cell is considered invalid; you can highlight validation errors, and any cell that doesn't meet data validation criteria will be red-circled. In other words, data validation allows you to *validate* user input - and constrain it to a degree - it's still your job to check if data validation is screaming "this cell contains invalid data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste this into sheet's module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In [E14:E1000]
        If Len(cell) <> 10 Then
            MsgBox "Text length in cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ does not equal to 10.", vbExclamation
            Application.Undo
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Explanation**

When you paste text onto sheet, the procedure scans each cell in a range. As soon as it finds text with length more than 10, it notifies user which cell breaks the limit and undoes all the changes with `Application.Undo`. Then it immediately exits.

Comment: Alternatively, `If Len(cell.Value) > 10 Then cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 10)`, to truncate the pasted input. Note that you should also check if `IsError(cell.Value)` before treating it like a string, otherwise expect *type mismatch* errors at one point or another.

Comment: @Mat'sMug :) :)

Comment: It looks like this applies to all cells, how can i make it so that it's only for range "E14:E1000"? Also, the length of the cell should be 10, would I instead change it to "If Len(cell) <> 10...."?